# How To Retrieve the Related List Data?

Tags: apex, soql, relationships

I have a Object called `SiteContracts__c` and it has a Related List Object is `Engineer_CheckList__c`", now I want to get the `Engineer_CheckList__c` record which is related to `SiteContracts__c` how can I retrieve those records using SOQL ?

For the records in `Engineer_CheckList__c` object we have Lookup to select the `SiteContracts__c`.

Update:

I am getting the following Error while using this Query through Developer Console

> Id, Name, (Select Id, Name From Engineer_Checklist__r) From
>   SiteContracts__c ^ ERROR at Row:1:Column:40 Didn't understand
>   relationship 'Engineer_Checklist__r' in FROM part of query call. If
>   you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the
>   '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL
>   or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Answer (score 3):

You can use an inner Query.

```
SELECT id,name, (SELECT id FROM Engineer_CheckLists__r ) FROM SiteContracts__c
```

then you can iterate through the list.

```
for(SiteContracts__c s :[select id,name,(select id from Engineer_CheckLists__r ) from SiteContracts__c] ){
    for(Engineer_CheckList__c e: s.Engineer_CheckLists__r){
          //do something
     }
}
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: Welcome to salesforce.stackexchange Raviteja, using the binary button in the editor your can format code. I've gone ahead and done that for you on this occasion.

Answer (score 3):

Karti, probably *Didn't understand relationship 'Engineer_Checklist__r* says that relationship name is different than 'Engineer_Checklist__r'.

Ensure that relation name is correct, you can use https://workbench.developerforce.com tooll

Go to: Info -> standard & custom obj (choose your object) -> Child relationship -> relationshipName

Answer (score 2):

The following SOQL statement will give you a list of `SiteContracts__c` records with reference to each `Engineer_checklist__c` record it is related to.

```
list<SiteContracts__c> cons = [Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name From Engineer_CheckLists__r) 
                                From SiteContracts__c];
```

This assumes the child relationship name for your lookup field on the SiteContracts__c object is Engineer_CheckLists.  You can confirm this by going to your lookup field and looking for the 'Child Relationship Name' field.  whatever is in that field you need to add "__r" to it.

You can add additional fields to each object if you would like.  You can learn more about nested queires and relationship queries here

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm

Comment: Thanks for the Quick help sfdc_ninja but I have already tried this in Developer Console the Query is Parsing an Error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Id, Name, (Select Id, Name From Engineer_Checklist__r) From SiteContracts__c
                                ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:40
Didn't understand relationship 'Engineer_Checklist__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.

Comment: You did not add the 's' to the relationship name.  Try `Engineer_Checklists__r`

Comment: Tried But Same Error..

Comment: Did you follow my instructions in the answer and look at the Child Relationship Name Field on the lookup field page?  You need to take whatever is in that field and append '__r' to it.

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a Look up field in the SiteContracts__c object, Here I have only the related list and in Engineer_Checklist__c object only I have Look up field to select the SiteContracts__c. but i need the related list record from the SiteContracts__s.

Comment: This is a quote from your original question stating there is a lookup.  If that is not the case, you should change your question.  **"For the records in Engineer_CheckList__c object we have Lookup to select the SiteContracts__c."**

Comment: Again sorry  sfdc_ninja, See I have 2 objects Called 'A' and 'B' in A object B is a related list and in B Object A is a Lookup field. Now I want to select the  from B object Records which is a related list in A object. i don wanna go to B object, Kindly help me Since I am a beginner in SF. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

ADD 'S' to the object name in the query,

Select Id, Name, (Select Id, Name From **Engineer_CheckLists__r**) 
                                From SiteContracts__c

Thanks,
Raviteja